# The change to the taskbar is massively annoying

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I mean this change:

[image: Taskbar]

Specifically the number in the orange square, which is related in some vague to the number of posts that have needed review in the last day or so.

When it shows "20" this implies to me that there are 20 outstanding reviews required. Only there aren't. When I click the "20" or the "review" link there are no reviews pending. This used to show the number of edits pending, and I can see the case for making it show the number of pending reviews of all kinds. However I can't see the case for making it show effectively random numbers.

Comment: Huh, wha? It's supposed to be a total. Maybe it's cached a bit too heavily -- this makes sense on Stac Overflow, but less for Physics

Comment: Hehehehehe ... massively annoying *by design*. Though I don't find it so since I understood the things Shog talks about in his answer.

Comment: [Original announcement of the change in the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/184688).

Answer (score 2):

They're not random: if the bar shows 20, then there are actually 20 pending review tasks.

However, unlike the numbers shown to you and everyone else in /review, this number counts *everything* - including tasks you aren't personally eligible to review. This includes tasks you've already done, tasks you've skipped, and tasks that the system expects you might not be sufficiently impartial to review (e.g., things you've already flagged or posted).

Like many of [the 10K tools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), this is intended to be *informational,* something to give you a high-level overview of what's happening on your site. If the number is getting bigger, there's a problem *even if you personally are reviewing everything you can!*

Comment: OK, I see the point, but as it was before the appearance of the orange square meant I had to leap into action to deal with pending edits. Now I have to remember that the square was showing "20" last time I looked so any number higher than "20" is a cue to action. Unless of course some tasks have been dealt with in which case "19" might also mean I have work to do. The point is that it is now effectively useless as a cue to me that I have to do something.

Comment: If this is the case, it would be helpful to dumb down the colour to some sort of gray when there are no further actionable posts. By all means show me this information, but don't pester me like you need me to go there! This would also alert me when there are further actionable reviews, and I would be more likely to go there.

Comment: Update: just posted [a mother-meta feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231051/please-dim-the-color-of-the-review-task-counter-when-there-are-no-actionable-tas) on this.